# how do I split parsed html output using python?

Tags: python

I have this html

```
<tr class="BgWhite"> 
 <td headers="th6" valign="top">
    0070648261<br/>QTY: 3
 </td>
</tr>
```

I want to obtain "0070648261" and "3" separately as in ID = 0070648261 and quantity = 3. I was able to use the code below

```
container1.find("td", {"headers": "th6"}).text.strip()
```

to produce this output

```
   0070648261<br/>QTY: 3
```

but how do I split and the output to get

ID = 0070648261  quantity = 3 ?

Comment: Just split the string... Using split function

Comment: What HTML parsing library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
a="0070648261<br/>QTY: 3"
a=a.split("<br/>")
a="ID = "+a[0]+" quantity ="+a[1].split(':')[1]
```

Output:

```
'ID = 0070648261 quantity = 3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to do that with regex?

```
import re
s = '<tr class="BgWhite"> <td headers="th6" valign="top">0070648261<br/>QTY: 3</td></tr>'

res = re.findall(r'(\d+)<br/>QTY: (\d+)', s)[0]
print('ID = {} quantity = {}'.format(res[0], res[1]))
```

Comment: _it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML._
 - from the post you sent above

Comment: Right, but the question already parsed down to the inner tag, so while this solution works, you could also just use the string that was output